# Can I get D visa in Estonia by carrying C visa from Finland?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, study, long-stay-visas

I need some help regarding of getting D visa to study in Estonia. While I'm proceeding C visa to Finland to visit friends in my country.

I have been offered a master's program at a university in Estonia. The first semester begins on the 29th of August. I was informed by the university that I needed to fly to any embassies of Estonia located in the third countries(not in Schengen). Yet, I also have a plan to visit my friends in Helsinki, Finland around the 1st of July and then arrive at Tartu for my study.

Therefore, I would like to inquire with you about getting the D Visa in Estonia while I will be holding the Schengen visa for Finland.

According to
[https://vm.ee/en/long-stay-d-visa#:~:text=A%20long%2Dstay%20(D),the%20period%20of%20180%20days](https://vm.ee/en/long-stay-d-visa#:%7E:text=A%20long%2Dstay%20(D),the%20period%20of%20180%20days).
, it is stated that

> "A long-stay visa must be applied for in person at an Estonian representation which handles visa applications or at a service point of the Police and Border Guard Board in Estonia."

I'm aware of the information stated in https://ut.ee/en/visainfo,

> "Entering the Schengen zone to study for a period of longer than 90 days is not in accordance with the laws and regulations of visa-free travelling and it may cause problems when you reach the first Schengen area country"

Also the information from the embassy of Finland, https://finlandabroad.fi/web/tha/how-to-apply-for-a-visa , that

> Granting a visa is subject to the condition that the person in question leaves the Schengen area before the visa expires. This is why a visa cannot be granted to anyone who intends to enter Finland in order to apply for a residence permit or wait for a decision on a residence permit. This also applies to family members of Finnish citizens.

Therefore, I am worried.
Can I get to Finland using a C visa, a.k.a. the Schengen Visa, and then apply for the D visa and residence permit at the service point in Estonia? Will there be any consequence regarding the 90/180-day rule and overlapping time between these two visas? If so, I would like to know what the problems or consequences would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Will there be any consequence regarding the 90/180-day rule and overlapping time between these two visas?

No, time spent on the soil of the issuing country of a D visa doesn't count towards the 90/180 clock

> Granting a visa is subject to the condition that the person in question leaves the Schengen area before the visa expires. This is why a visa cannot be granted to anyone who intends to enter Finland in order to apply for a residence permit or wait for a decision on a residence permit. This also applies to family members of Finnish citizens.

Excluding lying by omission (which can turn out pretty badly), if you give that plan to a Finnish visa official, you are pretty sure you will be denied, like stated in the text, thay will not accept someone who doesn't intend to leave the Area before the 90 days expire.
Nothing, other than an actual visa, can tell the Finnish official that you will actually be issued a visa by Estonia. In that situation nothing would prevent you being refused one/not applying at all and switching to become an illegal immigrant

Even to be granted a visa to Finland you will **need** that Estonian visa as a way to prove why you will not leave the Area after the visa expires

**TL;DR** : Get your Estonian visa and **then** apply for your Finnish visa using the Estonian visa and the appropriate documentation to prove that you are legally allowed to stay further than 90 days in Estonia